# gcc cannot find -lgcc, g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I'm trying to use MingGW on Windows but when I try to compile my c/c++ files, following error occurs when I compile with C(gcc)

```
> gcc c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C_C++\helloworld\hello.c - o c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C_C++\helloworld/hello

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and following error occurs when I compile with C++(g++)

```
> g++ c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C_C++\helloworldcpp\hello.cpp -o c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C_C++\helloworldcpp/hello

g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

The path variable is *C:\MinGW\bin* . I've downloaded mingw-developer-toolkit, mingw32-base, mingw32-gcc-g++ and msys-base among the basic setup packages. Also I'm getting #include error for iostream. I've tried almost all of the methods out in the internet but couldn't fix.

Comment: have you tried using gcc outside visual studio code? does `g++.exe` exist in the `C:\MinGW\bin` directory?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes but the same error occurs. There is g++.exe in the C:\MinGW\bin and typing gcc -v or g++ -v in command prompt works

Comment: If it fails outside visual studio code then I suggest you simplify your question by removing all reference to vs-code and just show the gcc commands that are failing

Comment: How exactly did you install MinGW? Which installer (if any did you use) and which options did you select?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I used MinGW installation manager and selected mingw-developer-toolkit, mingw32-base, mingw32-gcc-g++ and msys-base. I am using administrator account, if that's necessary.

Comment: sounds like something went wrong, try re-installing

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, re-installing solved the issue. I am still not sure what the problem was but thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like MinGW wasn't installed correctly.

Re-installing it will likely fix the issue.