# MINGW gfortran error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran, mingw32

Doing a MINGW install to compile Fortran on a laptop and running into this error.

The simple program:

```
program hello
    implicit none
    
    print *, 'Hello from FORTRAN!'
end program hello
```

The compiling commad:

```
gfortran hello.f90 -o hello
```

The error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lquadmath
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The packages I installed with the MinGW Installation Manager were

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base-bin
- mingw32-gcc-fortran-bin
- msys-base-bin

I've looked for other packages containing those files in the manager but I'm not sure where they'd be so I can install them. Any ideas?

Comment: Try mingw32-gfortran hello.f90 -o hello

Comment: No joy on this command. Same error returned.

Comment: You have installed gcc-fortran. I don't know which packages are installed by default with mingw but you might also need to install something like mingw32-gcc. To test if it is installed try to run `gcc`.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183515/gcc-cannot-find-lgcc-g-exe-error-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory) you have a similar issue. They suggested reinstalling mingw.

Comment: That work Emilio. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per user Emilio in the comments directing to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183515/gcc-cannot-find-lgcc-g-exe-error-createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory), a restart fixed the issue.